# (Advanced) Sql queries on database association table

Tags: sql, database, select

Assuming one has the following tables on an association in a database:

```
Customer(Id, Name, City),

Orders(Cust_Id, Prod_Id),

Product(Id, Name, Price, Country)
```

Taken for granted that a `Customer` has ordered a particular `Product` only once, I would like to execute the following queries:

1) Get the `Customers` ordered **all** the `Products` coming from `Country` "XY".

Is that the solution?:

```
Select * 
from Customers c 
join Orders o on c.id = o.orders.cust_id
join Product p on o.prod_id = p.id
where p.id = (Select id from Product where Product.country = "XY")
```

2) Get the `Customers` ordered `Products` **only** from the `Country` "XY"

What are the right queries in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

1) Customers who ordered all the products of a specific country:

```
DECLARE @Country AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @Country = 'XY'
;WITH OrdersCTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM   Orders
    WHERE  Prod_Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Product WHERE Country = @Country)
)
SELECT * 
FROM   Customers
WHERE  Id IN 
(
    SELECT Cust_Id 
    FROM   OrdersCTE
    GROUP BY Cust_Id 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Prod_Id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE Country = @Country)
)
```

2) Customers who bought only products of a specific country:

```
DECLARE @Country AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @Country = 'XY'
SELECT   C.Id,
         C.Name,
         C.City
FROM     Customers C
         Left JOIN Orders O
             ON C.Id = O.Cust_Id
         LEFT JOIN Product P
             ON P.Id = O.Prod_Id
GROUP BY C.Id,
         C.Name,
         C.City
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT Country) = 1
```